# How implement Mule App as a OAuth2 Resource Server of Restful Services

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, mule

How implement an Component that publish secure services Rest , conditions:

- These services should be secured by OAuth 2.0.
- This component will is the Resource Server.
- The Authorization Server is third party component implemented with Spring OAuth2.0 and Deployed in JBoss Server.
- The client app will be called to resouce server, using JavaScript or RestTemplate Client.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already developing other legs of the OAuth2 solution using Spring Security, there is no reason to not use it as OAuth implementation for Mule as well.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager

There is some also prepared things in Mule, if you run the commercial version, check htis out: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+STS+OAuth+2.0a+Example+Application

Comment: my re-question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915894/mule-oauth2-resource-server-and-authorization-provider